# Display Results of Form Submission on New Tab or Window

Tags: javascript, forms

There are several variations of this question already out there but I don't see the solution to this one specifically. Although I don't actually need this functionality it is killing me that I CAN'T make it work!

I have a field that allows the visitor to type in a URL and it will take them there.

```
<form name="urlField" onsubmit="return submitURLFieldForm();">
  <input type="text" name="address" id="addressfield" />
</form>
```

The JS that handles this so that the necessary protocol is not left off is (special thanks to @[h2ooooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247893/h2ooooooo) ):

```
function submitURLFieldForm() {
var url = document.getElementById('addressfield').value;
if (!url.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//)) {
    url = 'http://' + url;
}

window.location.href = url; 
return false;
}
```

If I add a `target="_blank"` to my opening form tag it doesn't work. Why? And where should I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never submitting the form.

You have an event handler that, when the form starts to submit, sets `location` and prevents the normal form submission.

Use `window.open(url)` instead of that if you want to open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

```
var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

You can try this  :)

happy coding :)

Comment: both yours & @Quentin's answers work and make perfect sense. seeing the answer like this, and how simple it is, sure makes me feel stupid for asking the question!

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm:ya i know but sometimes it drives everyone really crazy.